# Performance of Task

Tags: c#, .net-core

Given the following:

```
public class Foo
{
    public Bar Bar { get; } = new Bar();
}

public class Bar
{
    public string Baz => "Baz";
}

Foo f = new Foo();
```

If I do this a large number of times:

```
f.Bar.Baz;
```

It takes about 0.02μs for each operation. If I do this lots of times:

```
Task.Run(() => f.Bar.Baz).Wait();
```

It takes about 100μs for each operation.

I expect *some* overhead of using a Task, but my question is simply whether that is a reasonable overhead, or am I missing something?

My purpose is that ultimately I will be using LINQ Expressions to build an expression tree (from some configuration entered by a user in a UI) and then compiling a delegate. I need to invoke the delegate in such a way that I can time it out. That means running 'in another thread' somehow and waiting on the result for a finite time (to be clear, I understand this will not really time out the operation, it will continue running until the task completes, but I will have a mechanism to fail the operation and record that it was suspect, so it doesn't run again).

I expect most of the operations to be of the type illustrated, so to execute very quickly and making them 100 times slower seems a bit of a downer

Comment: Is your scenario realistic? Why would you need to time out the creation of a new object? Of course it looks like a 100x overhead at the moment. But given your real procedure takes 0.2 seconds, the overhead is only 0.05%

Comment: you're optimising at the wrong point. maintainable, scalable code is *much* more important than a few microseconds.

Comment: How many times do you need to run this operation? If you only start a single task from a user action, the user in unlikely to notice the 100μs extra time. 100x a small value can still be a small value.

Comment: @ThomasWeller - what I meant was the operations in question will mostly be just property access (f.Bar.Baz), but they will be against classes containing real data, not against Foo and Bar with static content. I just tested with Foo and Bar to get the timings - the overhead all seems to be associated with use of Task

Comment: it wouldn't slow a more intensive task down by 100 times. most of the overhead you are seeing right now is the setup time of the task. if you are looking to check what the performance impact on a set workload is its best to simulate it with that sort of workload or at least something similar.

Think about taking a bus. taking a bus a couple feet would be horribly inefficient however over the length of a city the time it takes to get on the bus and pay the fair is almost non existent.